# IE8 is posting form data partially

Tags: forms, post, internet-explorer-8

Everything was working perfectly ... suddenly after I installed Visual studio 2010 beta2, IE8 started to behave strangely.
Only the data that was sent to the browser gets posted back when submit button is clicked. Any additional fields are ignored and are nulls. It works perfectly on FireFox 3.5+.

I uninstalled Visual studio 2010 beta2 ... but the problem remains ... I will try system restore later as last option.

Edit:
After farther investigation the problem was with jquery submit() handling on IE8 ... it is bogous:

```
 $(function() {
 $('form').submit(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    setTimeout(
    function() {
        $(this).attr('disabled', '');
    },
 5000);
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After farther investigation the problem was with jquery submit() handling on IE8 ... it is bogous:

```
$(function() {
 $('form').submit(function() {
  $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 setTimeout(
 function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', '');
},
5000);
});
});
```

I think they are working on it in jquery 1.4 ... but I will wait for the whole plugin community to catch up

Answer (score 0):

I would check your HTML and make sure it is valid. Browsers try to fix your HTML if it is malformed, usually with crazy side-effects like you are mentioning. That also explains why one browser behaves differently than another, because they choose to fix your HTML differently.